# Communicate between React's child-component

Tags: reactjs, this

I already asked similar question but i got new a problem). I want while click on child-component perform function of parent-component.

```
var Fructs = ['banana', 'mango', 'potato'];

var Kaka = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}> Hell o forld </div>
  }
});

var Application = React.createClass({
  handle() {
    console.log("took took");
  },
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    var mass = Fructs.map(function(data, index) {
      return <Kaka key={index} onClick={handle.bind(this)}/>
    });
    return (
      <div>
        { mass }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Application />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/kiresuah/pen/EgVgzR?editors=1011)
All work perfect if child-component is one. But if i try generate list of child-component it doesn't work. Error's log write that "this" isn't find.
I find similar a problem [doc React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), but i do it wronп (. Please, tell what i do wrong?

Comment: The working example in the codepen is different from the code in your question. Which would you like us to analyse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set this for `.map` callback., also you `handle` is method, in order to get it you need use `this.handle` after changes `.map` should looks like this

```
var mass = Fructs.map(function(data, index){
  return <Kaka key={index} onClick={ this.handle.bind(this) } />
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ - get Component method 
}, this);
   ^^^^ - callback context
```

```js
var Fructs = ['banana', 'mango', 'potato'];

var Kaka = React.createClass({
  render() { 
   return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
     Hell o forld     
   </div>
  }
})

var Application = React.createClass({
  handle() {
    console.log("took took");
  },
  
  render() {
    var mass = Fructs.map(function(data, index){
      return <Kaka key={index} onClick={ this.handle.bind(this) } />
    }, this);

    return <div>
      { mass }
    </div>
  }
})

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Application />
    </div>
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App  />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```